# My computer won't POST when I install my new video card

Tags: graphics-card, post

My current Windows 7 32-bit system won't POST when I install my new Radeon HD5770 video card.  When I pull out my new video card and replace it with my old nVidia 8800 GTS, it boots into windows fine.  When my computer fails to POST with the new video card installed, my MSI K8N Neo2 motherboard hangs with a status code of "60" on the diagnostic LED, but I can't find my mobo manual online or anywhere that contains the list of status codes and their definitions to see what that code means.  Any ideas?

Other notes, the new video card says it supports PCI-Express 2.1, but my motherboard doesn't, not sure if that matters.

Thanks in advance for all your help!  I'm going to begin researching this problem right now, but I thought I'd post this quick question in the meantime just to give me a boost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Does the new video card work in another system?
- Is there an extra power-supply cable you're forgetting to connect (eg a 75W 6-pin PCIe connector)?
- Is your power supply capable?  (The [HD5770 system requirements](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5770/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5770-system-requirements.aspx) show a 450W PSU with 6-pin PCIe connector is necessary, and provide a link to finding information on [which PSUs are certified](http://ati.amd.com/certifiedPSU) for use with ATI graphics cards.)

The system requirements do not seem to *require* PCIe 2.1, so you may be in the clear there (only a 16-lane (x16) PCIe slot is listed as required).  Sometimes it's hard to tell if *"supports" new-tech-version* really means *"requires"*.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't have another system to test the new video card, so I'm not sure.  I'm pretty sure I'm not forgetting any extra power-supply cable as it only requires the 6-pin that you mentioned.  My power supply is a 700W, it should suffice.

Comment: @dr dork: you might double-check the certification link to see if you can eliminate the PSU from suspicion.  it's possible you've gotten a dead card and should get a replacement from your vendor, but that's hard to tell for certain if you don't have another system to test with.

Comment: i checked the PSU certification link and my PSU has indeed been certified.  Unfortunately, I live in a very remote part of Texas on a lake and don't know anyone that has another computer I can test this card in.  Unless I can find any other ideas, my only remaining alternatives are return the card for a replacement in the hopes that it's bad or buy an entirely new computer (which I was planning to do anyways) in the hopes that one of my current components (most likely the mobo) is causing incompatibility issues. Either way, thanks so much for your ideas, as they were ideas I didn't think of!

Comment: @dr dork: np.  everything else seems like it should work, so I'd return the card as DOA.  if you get it replaced with another of the same model, and it also doesn't work, it's more likely you're looking at an incompatibility with your current components.  good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think problem might be in BIOS of your board.

I had very similar problem with MSI 945GCM5-F V2 and RadeonHD 5770.
Then I read on some forum that it was due to misunderstanding between card PCIE version protocol and BIOS of MB. Guy from the forum requested updated BIOS from MSI support and they have send it to him.

I did the same and got BIOS that was perfectly able to POST with 5770. This BIOS was not on the site, only through MSI support channel.

Answer (score 0):

Based on *[MSI K8N Neo2 Platinum Motherboard BIOS's](http://www.lejabeach.com/MSIK8N/k8nneo2.html)*, I presume you have a [Phonenix Technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Technologies) BIOS. The BIOS Central [Phoenix BIOS Post Codes](http://www.bioscentral.com/postcodes/phoenixbios.htm) list associates 60 with a memory test during POST.