# Peripherals don't Turn on When New Graphics Card is Installed

Tags: boot, graphics-card, bios, post

I recently decided to upgrade my graphics card. I bought a Radeon HD 7750 to replace my relatively underpowered Nvidia GT 620. However, when I plug in the new card, my computer's peripherals do not power on. Additionally, my bootloader (GRUB2) doesn't seem to start.

I am guessing this means my computer does not complete POST. I know this is related to the graphics card in specific for the following reasons:

- Reverting to ONLY the old card makes my computer work again.
- If I plug this card into any port, BIOS does not complete POST.
- If I use it in addition to my old card, BIOS still does not complete POST.

So, you can see that BIOS does see the hardware, but it keeps the computer from properly booting. My system is a Lenovo ThinkCentre K430. How can I solve this issue?

Here is the steps I followed to install the graphics card:

1. Uninstall proprietary Nvidia drivers.
2. Power off the computer and unplug the power cable.
3. Remove the old card and replace it with the new one, which fit perfectly.
4. Plug in monitors.
5. Turn on.

Comment: If POST fails and you're provding enough power to the card (and all other peripherals), then consider the new card faulty and try  another new card of the same make/model, and/or try it in another computer. If you don't have spare parts and computers around to test with, then contact a local computer repair shop who does, and get them to diagnose, and perhaps install, the card for you.

Comment: Specific model information on both cards is required to look up installation instructions. Both seem to have low profile versions which indicate both could or could not have require additional pci-e power cables.  I found random models of each card, the Nvidia 652 GT requires a ~350W power supply.  The Radeon HD 7750 requires 450W power supply.  My educated guess is you will need to replace the power supply.

Comment: It sounds like the power supply is too weak, defective, or a power cable isn't connected to the card.  [See also this very similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/112654/my-computer-wont-post-when-i-install-my-new-video-card?rq=1)

Comment: I would guess the power supply, but Lenovo actually tested this card to work with my particular model. [Here's the link](https://www.lenovo.com/products/us/desktop/ideacentre/k-series/k430/K430_Datasheet.pdf).

Comment: @dillmo You could try disconnecting other peripherals from the power supply to attempt to free up more wattage for the card.  For example, remove any powered USB devices, disconnect cdrom/dvd players, secondary harddrives, or any PCI expansion cards like sound, NIC.  If this allows it to boot you know it's the psup and not the video card.

Comment: How many watts is your power supply?

Comment: Most video card require an additional power cord in the form of a 6 or 8 pin connector.  Did you connect the power cord to the video card?

Comment: @cybernard My card doesn't require an additional connector. The PCI slot should be enough.

Comment: @jlehtinen Sadly, your solution didn't work. I can also confirm that the graphics card does power on, as the fan is active when my PC powers on.

Comment: @dillmo Go with techi007's suggestions.  You may have to RMA the card.